# Use Eigen Map in OpenMP reduction

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen

I want to use Eigen matrices in combination with OpenMP reduction.

In the following is a small example of how I do it (and it works). The object `myclass` has three attributes (an Eigen matrix, two integers corresponding to its dimension) and a member function `do_something` that uses an omp reduction on a sum which I define because Eigen matrices are not standard types.

```
#include "Eigen/Core"

class myclass {
public:
    Eigen::MatrixXd m_mat;
    int m_n; // number of rows in m_mat
    int m_p; // number of cols in m_mat

    myclass(int n, int p); // constructor

    void do_something(); // omp reduction on `m_mat`
}

myclass::myclass(int n, int p) {
    m_n = n;
    m_p = p;
    m_mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(m_n,m_p); // init m_mat with null values
}

#pragma omp declare reduction (+: Eigen::MatrixXd: omp_out=omp_out+omp_in)\
    initializer(omp_priv=MatrixXd::Zero(omp_orig.rows(), omp_orig.cols()))

void myclass::do_something() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd tmp = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(m_n, m_p); // temporary matrix
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:tmp)
    for(int i=0; i<m_n;i++) {
        for(int l=0; l<m_n; l++) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_p; j++) {
                tmp(l,j) += 10;
            }
        }
    }
    m_mat = tmp;
}
```

**Problem:** OpenMP does not allow (or at least not all implementations) to use reduction on class members but only on variables. Thus, I do the reduction on a temporary matrix and I have this copy at the end `m_mat = tmp` which I would like to avoid (because `m_mat` can be a big matrix and I use this reduction a lot in my code).

**Wrong fix:** I tried to use Eigen Map so that `tmp` corresponds to data stored in `m_mat`. Thus, I replaced the omp reduction declaration and the `do_something` member function definition in the previous code with:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (+: Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>: omp_out=omp_out+omp_in)\
    initializer(omp_priv=MatrixXd::Zero(omp_orig.rows(), omp_orig.cols()))

void myclass::do_something() {
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> tmp = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(m_mat.data(), m_n, m_p);
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:tmp)
    for(int i=0; i<m_n;i++) {
        for(int l=0; l<m_n; l++) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_p; j++) {
                tmp(l,j) += 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it does not work anymore and I get the following error at compilation:

> error: conversion from ‘const ConstantReturnType {aka const
>   Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp,
>   Eigen::Matrix >}’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘Eigen::Map, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >’
>   requested
>        initializer(omp_priv=Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(omp_orig.rows(), omp_orig.cols()))

I get that the implicit conversion from `Eigen::MatrixXd` to `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>` does not work in the omp reduction but I don't know how to make it work.

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:** I forgot to mention that I use gcc v5.4 on a Ubuntu machine (tried both 16.04 and 18.04)

**Edit 2:** I modified my example as there was no reduction in the first one. This example is not exactly what I do in my code, it is just a minimum "dumb" example.

Comment: I am not all that familiar with the details of how Eigen is implemented, but I assume they support move semantics, in which case that seems like the simplest solution? (In fact, are you sure that's not what happens anyway? )

Comment: You mean when I do `m_mat = tmp`, it changes the pointer related to `m_mat` to point to `tmp` instead of doing an hard copy from `tmp` to `m_mat` ?

Comment: Your example does not implement a reduction. Each thread will process its own set of rows of `tmp` without concurrent access.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I am changing it. I am not exactly doing this in my code and I fail to simplify it to a minimum example. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Eigen::Map` can only be created over an existing memory buffer. In your example, the underlying OpenMP implementation will try to do something like that:

```
Eigen::Map<MatrixXd> tmp_0 = MatrixXd::Zero(r,c);
Eigen::Map<MatrixXd> tmp_1 = MatrixXd::Zero(r,c);
...
/* parallel code, thread #i accumulate in tmp_i */
...
tmp = tmp_0 + tmp_1 + ...;
```

and stuff like `Map<MatrixXd> tmp_0 = MatrixXd::Zero(r,c)` is of course not possible. `omp_priv` has to be a `MatrixXd`. I don't know if it's possible to customize the type of the private temporaries created by OpenMP. If not you can do the job by hand by creating a `std::vector<MatrixXd> tmps[omp_num_threads()];` and doing the final reduction yourself, or better: don't bother about making a single additional copy, it will be largely negligible compared to all other work and copies done by OpenMP itself.

Comment: Thank you, I understand better now.

Answer (score 4):

As @ggael mentioned in their answer, `Eigen::Map` can't be used for this because it needs to map to existing storage.  If you did make it work, all threads would use the same underlying memory which would create a race condition.

The likeliest solution to avoiding the temporary you create in the initial thread is to bind the member variable to a reference, which should always be valid for use in a reduction.  That would look something like this:

```
void myclass::do_something() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd &loc_ref = m_mat; // local binding
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:loc_ref)
    for(int i=0; i<m_n;i++) {
        for(int l=0; l<m_n; l++) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_p; j++) {
                loc_ref(l,j) += 10;
            }
        }
    }
    // m_mat = tmp; no longer necessary, reducing into the original
}
```

That said, note that this still creates a local copy of the zero matrix in each and every thread, much like @ggael showed in the example.  Using reduction in this way will be quite expensive.  If the actual code is doing something like the code snippet, where values are added based on nested loops like this the reduction could be avoided by dividing the work such that either:

1. each thread touches a different part of the matrix
2. an atomic is used to update the individual value

Solution 1 example:

```
void myclass::do_something() {
    // loop transposed so threads split across l
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int l=0; l<m_n; l++) {
        for(int i=0; i<m_n;i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_p; j++) {
                loc_ref(l,j) += 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution 2 example:

```
void myclass::do_something() {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<m_n;i++) {
        for(int l=0; l<m_n; l++) {
            for(int j=0; j<m_p; j++) {
                auto &target = m_mat(l,j);
                // use the ref to get a variable binding through the operator()
                #pragma omp atomic
                target += 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment. My algorithm is indeed different from this little example. I think that what you proposed first will work in my case. I know that I cannot avoid inner thread copies, but that won't be an issue. Thanks again